# Restrict creation of instance EC2 to t2.nano in a specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I’m struggling to build a policy which gives only the possibility to create EC2 instances with these criteria:

- in N. Virginia
- t1.micro or t2.nano
- volumes gp2 of 8 GiB

With the following code I get an error "The AMI ID (ami-007855ac798b5175e) is not valid. The AMI may no longer exist or may be specific to another account or region."

I’m lost...

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-east-1"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t1.micro",
                        "t2.nano"
                    ]
                },
                "NumericEquals": {
                    "ec2:VolumeSize": "8"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:VolumeType": "gp2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This policy does not use any fixed AMI.so the error message is not related to the policy itself. The policy only sets the conditions but not the AMI. What's even more interesting the AMI (Jammy Jellyfish) is available in us-east-1 N.Virginia (all AZ). In case you have any support plan - commercial account you may try solving this with AWS Support Team.

Comment: The policy alone won't generate this error message What command are you using that generates this error message? Please show us your code / AWS CLI command.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify all actions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2ManagementPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:RegisterImage",
                "ec2:DeregisterImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```